# Div on the sides taking all available space in pure CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` horizontally centered that is 960px (width). I have have a second `<div>` at the right side and a third at the left Side.

I want the divs at the sides to take all available space minus the 960 px of the centered div. I succedded for the div at the right side (with `overflow: hidden`). But I failed for the div at the left side.

```
<div id="left">leftt</div>
<div id="center">center</div>
<div id="right">right</div>

<style>
#center{
    width: 960px;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #bbb;
}
#left{
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: ?;
}
#right{
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: ?;
}

<style>
```

here is what i want.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgdLo.png

Comment: Show the HTML and CSS.

Comment: What are the heights of the div

Comment: The height of the div is not important, let's say 50px. i don't have HTML CSS to show because i didn't succeed in finding a solution, that is why i am here.

Comment: So if the window width is equal or less than 980px, the left and right divs don't appear. Only when the window width is greater than 980 px, this divs begin to expand to take the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css tables (IE8 supports them - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-table))

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/r3Q5B/)**

1) Set `display:table` on container div

2) Set `display:table-cell` on child divs

3) Set `min-width:960px` on center div and `width:50%` on side divs

### CSS

```
.container
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#center{
    min-width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    display: table-cell;
}
#left{

    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}
#right{

    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Modern browser(IE9+, firefox, chrome)
in Html:

```
<body>
  <div id="left">leftt</div>
  <div id="center">center</div>
  <div id="right">right</div>
</body>
```

in css:

```
#center{
  width: 960px;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
#left{
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  width: calc(50% - 480px);
}
#right{
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  width: calc(50% - 480px);
}
```

In IE8 Use JQuery:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    var documentWidth = $("body").width();
    $("#left").width((documentWidth - 960) / 2);
    $("#right").width((documentWidth - 960) / 2);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, but is there not a solution for IE8?

Comment: Ie8 doesn't support expression - "Dynamic properties (also called "CSS expressions"). you must use JQuery or other javascript library

Comment: I got this problem for a test, testers said its possible even for IE7, But really hard. Don't you have any hint to guide me? with <table> perhaps?

Comment: Thank you, but like i said in the title of the topic, i need to do it in Pure CSS/HTML